# Android: 404 error for REST API endpoint in android emulator but works perfectly in browser

Tags: android, rest

Heading says it all really. To make this even stranger, there is a development environment/API in which this particular endpoint works perfectly, but the production one doesn't. They are both producing the exact same response in the browser, but in Android emulator only the development one works.

Further details:
*It is a POST endpoint with no body.
*The development environment endpoint does have an authentication header, but the browser doesn't produce an authentication error for the production one and it works fine. I tried clearing the cache to make sure it wasn't holding a cookie for it, so it can't be attributed to that.
*Everything I've found on this so far only pertains to Ionic. This is native android. 
*EDIT: also does not work on actual device either.

Comment: Make sure there is connectivity between emulater and dev environment. By 404, I understand resource not found and not something to do with access denied due to authentication (which is 403). Please correct if my understanding is wrong

Comment: 404 definitely means resource not found but its also just the code and I think the api dev has used that code as the catchall for everything. There's definitely connectivity because other endpoints work on the dev environment.